# How to store the .txt file in SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I created application of write and read file. When I click button, my file is write and also read the file on the same button click. I want as and when my file is write, that file is save it into SQLite. I'm surfing on the net but can't find proper source or ideas how to do this.

And that file is compare with input String something like "code". If this input_String is match with that file which is store in the SQLite database, if match user can't go ahead for the further process. I am seeking advice on this. Here is my code.

The Activity class:

```
public class Write extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText myText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.abc);
        myText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        Button createButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        Button readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                createFile(myText.getText().toString());
                myText.setText("");
                readFile();
            }
        });

        
    }

    private void createFile(String Text)
    {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try
        {
            fos = openFileOutput("mynote.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(Text.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File created succesfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("CreateFile", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        finally
        {
            if (fos != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    // drain the stream
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the DataBase_Adapter code:

```
//Table Name
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_CODE="code_table";
    
  //Colum,n Names
    public static final String KEY_CODE_ID="ID";
    public static final String KEY_CODE_NAME="USERNAME";
    
    
  //Table Create Statement 
    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_CODE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME_CODE+" ("+KEY_CODE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+KEY_CODE_NAME+"TEXT)";
    
    //Insert Code in Database code_table
    public void saveCode(String strKey_Code)
    {
       ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        newValues.put(KEY_CODE_NAME , strKey_Code);
      

        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME_CODE, null, newValues);
       
    }
```

Comment: why don't u just save the contents of the text file as a `TEXT` in the DB ?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have taken could be improved a little bit, consider storing in the database only the name of the files, you already have the files saved, right? why store their content again in the database?